# Has my RAID drive failed?

Tags: linux, raid, performance, hard-drive, drive-failure

I checked the output of my server today and it said:

```
root@s01 [~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 1.1
  Creation Time : Sat Jul  7 18:23:24 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 2929751932 (2794.03 GiB 3000.07 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2929751932 (2794.03 GiB 3000.07 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Mon Jul  4 21:46:45 2016
          State : active, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : server.domain.com:1
           UUID : 58600fc5:5348d92c:a7d25465:20d42940
         Events : 2250926

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       50        1      active sync   /dev/sdd2

       0       8       34        -      faulty   /dev/sdc2
root@s01 [~]#
```

Does this mean that one of the drives failed? Do I need to completely replace the drive or are there some commands I can run to try and fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/sdc2` failed. It will need to be replaced.